# how to write a random code in c#

Tags: c#

… I'm working on random in C# . I want to use a random to view string move in random & this is the code which i write but it dosen't work
i want to know what wrong i do

```
using system ;
namespace work
{
    static random random =new random();
    static int max_X=console.windowwidth; 
    static int max_Y=console.windowheight;
    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        int x=random.next(max_X);
        int y=random.next(max_Y);
        console.setcursorposition(x,y);
        console.write("walaa");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in what way it does not work? Or is your problem the fact that the code does not compile?

Comment: First problem: C# is case-sensitive. None of your code will work at the moment. Next problem: you haven't said *how* it doesn't work, assuming that your *real* code uses the right casing...

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is happening? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @JonSkeet The lack of a class is perhaps a bigger problem than case-sensitivity

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True, had missed that. And the unbalanced braces.

Comment: Is this the actual code you are trying to run? Because there's no way this even compiles. To help you out we'll need real code, and preferably, the real error you're getting.

Comment: If you try to run the code, an error list will appear, showing you what is wrong. In addition, red squiggles appear in the editor. An explanation will pop up if you hover with the mouse over the squiggled text.

Comment: it combile & no errors but the output is constant not move

Comment: @WalaaElsaid No it does not compile. You did not post the real code, if the real code compiles.

Comment: It doesn't move because randomizing the mouse occurs only once - and it does this so fast that you see it as the original mouse position. How many times do you actually randomly reset the cursor position, in your code?

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is that your program does not compile. Here is a version that does:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
         static Random random = new Random();
         static int max_X = Console.WindowWidth; 
         static int max_Y = Console.WindowHeight;

         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             int x = random.Next(max_X);
             int y = random.Next(max_Y);
             Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
             Console.Write("walaa");
             Console.ReadLine();//keep console open so you can see output
         }
    }
}
```

In C#, in order to define methods, you need to define a class. That was missing in your code.

The other significant problem is that C# is sensitive to the case of text. That is, upper-case and lower-case text is treated as different by the compiler. For example, the class is named `Random` rather than `random`, and so on.

Your textbook will contain all this information and I suggest you revise the introductory sections of that book.

---

You ask how to make the text move around the screen. Do you mean like this?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
         static Random random = new Random();
         static int max_X = Console.WindowWidth; 
         static int max_Y = Console.WindowHeight;

         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             while (true)
             {
                 int x = random.Next(max_X);
                 int y = random.Next(max_Y);
                 Console.Clear();
                 Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                 Console.Write("walaa");
                 Thread.Sleep(500);
                 while (Console.KeyAvailable)
                 {
                     ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();
                     if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                     {
                         return;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for adding `Console.ReadLine();`. @WalaaElsaid: Without this addition, the console will close itself immediately after executing the code. `ReadLine` keeps it open until you hit `<Enter>`.

Comment: that is true but it still don't move

Comment: @WalaaElsaid It doesn't move because the code doesn't make it move. It prints a single 5 character string, and then terminates. If you want the text to move you need to program it so. You can't expect us to know what you expect the program's behaviour to be since you didn't say what you expected it to be.

Comment: it is ok can you tell me how can i make it move ??

Comment: the out put( walaa) i want it appear in one place then clear then in another place etc ... can you understan me ??

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new console project in Visual Studio (and in other IDE's) a text like the following is inserted

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Keep this general structure and place your code into the `Main` method between `{` and `}`.

---

UPDATE:

Make it move like this

```
while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
    int x = random.Next(max_X);
    int y = random.Next(max_Y);

    Console.Clear();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
    Console.Write("walaa");

    Thread.Sleep(500); // Pause in milliseconds
}
```

You will need to add a `using System.Threading;` before the namespace. This will run until some key is hit. The `Console.ReadLine()` is not required any more.

`while (condition) { statement_sequence }` is a loop statement. It will repeat the statements as long as the condition is fulfilled.